# How to make Puma reload everytime there are changes on .rb?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, reload

I use `thin` before for my `sinatra` app, and using `rerun` to automatically reload server when there are changes on .rb

```
rerun --pattern="**/*.{rb}" ruby ./main_service.rb
```

how to make `puma` do the same? since this command does not work:

```
rerun --pattern="**/*.{rb}" puma -b tcp://127.0.0.1:12345
```

that shows:

```
ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run
```

my `config.ru`:

```
require './main_service'
run Sinatra::Application
```

but when i use manual command `puma -b tcp://127.0.0.1:12345` it works normally..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hh nevermind, I found the solution:

```
rerun --pattern="**/*.{rb}" "bundle exec puma -b tcp://127.0.0.1:12345 ./config.ru"
```

the second rerun parameter must be quoted

Comment: In 2016, October, rails 5+, the above command gives the error: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - puma`